# Link to an externally created photo albums

Tags: functions

I have created a photoshop photo album which is in a folder (html code, photos etc). Is it possible to upload this folder and then link to it from a page in Wordpress?

Comment: Yes, why not. You can do that.

Comment: FTP it up or use your hosting control panel upload, then link to the url.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed the photo album in a page as follows:

- As mentiontioned by @amari, load your photoshop album to the server using FTP
- Create a new Page or Post in Wordpress
- In the editor using text input enter the iframe tag and point it to your uploaded photoshop album as follows:

  `<iframe src="https://link-to-your-gallery" width="100%"></iframe>`

You can find more information on the iframe attributes here [iframe - w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) to better style the embedded gallery.

I am never a fan of using iframe but it is a quick and easy way to do the job in this case.

You can use the embed tag as an alternative to iframe in much the same way:

`<embed src="https://link-to-your-gallery" width="800px" height="600px">`

The advantage of this is that the embed tag creates a container and this container can be styled using css to create the look that you want to achieve.